# storing input hex values from string in C

Tags: c, encoding, type-conversion, hex

I currently have a string argv input to my C program (i.e. ./a "123456"). Is there any way that I can convert this string into hex values (0x123456) without creating a conversion table?

Note that I want to convert the string directly into hex and store it for use (i.e. "\x12\x34\x56", not into ASCII hex values.

Comment: Take a look at `strtol`.

Comment: What should a string of `"123"` write? `"\x12\x30"`, `"\x01\x23"`, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The canonical function for converting a string to an integer in C, [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/), has a radix parameter, so you can just use:

```
int hex = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how I can use strtol to do this. My input string will be 20 bytes (20 hex values, 80 bits), and I need to put them in a (uint8_t *) buffer for use later on.

Comment: @gztes in that case do a loop over the string using sscanf e.g.